# DI in tests without using spring boot (@SpringBootTest)

Tags: spring

Switching from spring boot back to "normal" spring because the app only uses some jdbc code to "upsert" into a postgresql database.

1)
    tried annotating the test class with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DBIntegration {

results in:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

2)
   tried annotating the class with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {})
public class DBIntegration {

[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [de.mydomain.myproject.DBIntegration]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml}.

No exceptions, but java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=insertDataFrom_sometest],
```

3) tried annotating the class with:

```
@Component
public class DBIntegration {

dependency injection does not work in this case, the expected service
(to be injected) throws a nullpointerexception
```

Comment: What about using `@DataJpaTest`?

Comment: with that annotation i get the same message as in try #2, no tests found

Comment: actually this: https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/   (i know its the kong guy...) looks like its working. run into some other issues. will report back tomorrow

Comment: As you don't use `@SpringBootTest` you shoud prepare and feed the context yourself.